# get required format in ssis

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Hi I have doubt in ssis

source : emp

```
id |currency 
1  |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><double>0.7915</double>
2  |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><double>-1</double>
```

based on this table I want output like below

target : empdest

```
id | currency
1  | 0.7915
2  | -1
```

I tried like below in derived column expression

```
SUBSTRING(currency,50,(FINDSTRING(currency),"</",1)))
```

above expression not give expected result .

please tell me how to write  expression in ssis to 
solve this issue in ssis

Comment: Are you using a derivated column?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SUBSTRING(currency,48,(FINDSTRING(currency,"</",1)) - 48)
```

result:

```
0.7915
-1
```

SUBSTRING works in this way:
SUBSTRING(character_expression, position, **length**)
48 is the DISTANCE with the beginning of the searched value